# About the tag graph-algorithms

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Apparently there's a tag [graph-algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-algorithms).

My personal tagging choice has been [algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms) + [graphs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs). I think this covers graph algorithms pretty well.

Do we need/want a dedicated tag [graph-algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-algorithms)? If not, can we keep it as a synonym in some way?

Comment: Follow-up question: if we keep [tag:graph-algorithms], revisit the question if we need [tag:graphs].

Comment: Regarding [tag:graphs], please add links to relevant old meta discussions when reopening a discussed topic: [1](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/895/), [2](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/188/).

Answer (score 5):

Not that this really adds a lot, but it at least gives a place for people to vote in favour of discarding [graph-algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-algorithms) and using [algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms) + [graphs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs).

My perspective is that this is the more flexible route. We need a tag for algorithms (of course), and a tag for things-to-do-with-graphs (side note, I still think it's productive to have separate [graph-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) and [graphs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs) tags, in reference to Kaveh's comment), so [graph-algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-algorithms) is simply adding a superfluous tag that may make searching harder; someone looking for a graph algorithm has two fairly natural routes via tags using [algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms) + [graphs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs), and [graph-algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-algorithms) could possibly split the group of questions that should be found together.

Anyway, the votes for this answer can help decide.

Comment: Note to self: if/when we implement this, revisit [tag:search-algorithms] (cf [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/287/burninate-tags-search-algorithms-and-search-problem)).